# Typescript: How to override property in library interface from optional to required

Tags: typescript

I have an interface in a library with optional `id` field:

```
interface I {
  id?: string;
}
```

I want to override it so it's

```
interface I {
  id?: string;
}
```

So I declared module, redefined interface but I'm being refused by Typescript

```
import { Option as BaseUiOption } from "baseui/select";

declare module "baseui/select" {
  export interface Option extends BaseUiOption {
    // trying to override
    readonly id: string | number;

    // extending is ok
    readonly idx: string | number;
  }
}

const x: BaseUiOption = { id: "a", idx: "a" };

x.id.toString(); // Object is possibly 'undefined'. ts(2532)
x.idx.toString();
```

How can I override library's interface field optionality?

https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-forked-9q12h?file=/src/index.ts

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces)

> Non-function members of the interfaces should be unique. If they are not unique, they must be of the same type. The compiler will issue an error if the interfaces both declare a non-function member of the same name, but of different types.

In your case `readonly id: string | number;` is not assignable to `readonly id?: string | number;` because type is different.

You can try to add another interface :

```js
import { OptionWithId } from "baseui/select";

declare module "baseui/select" {
  export interface OptionWithId extends Option {
    readonly id: string | number;
    readonly idx: string | number;
  }
}

const x: OptionWithId = { id: "a", idx: "a" };

x.id.toString(); // string | number
x.idx.toString(); // string | number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgeTDYEB2B1YMAWAkgCZwC%20cAZlBCHAEQBGAhgM4CmArsAPQcA27AMYx6AbgBQE4sP7Mo7OCAjFOghiw7c%207QSPqIJcOOwAekWHGCYY7KJWZDFqdFlwESJ07czFWKNAxMQ2NjBWZiLH4ATytiAC44VhgoawBzOAAfOExOEEY7SVC4cMjMGLjTROTUzAzs3PzCo3IJMikhLGS4KoDXHDwiUgBeRDjE%20mZ6ABpKianySQlTADpgYhWYCABlFPSACgBKMTgeHiS9uqycvIKoZbXiVa3d2rSjk7OLt%20vGu4kgA)

Comment: Aight, so it's impossible to achieve, right? I need to override the interface, not create another one as it won't be implemented by the library.

Comment: I'm trying to be very careful when I need to say that something is impossible in TS :D
But according to the error message and docs it seems to be impossible